# Http interceptor Error Response in complete in chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am facing weird issue while working with httpinterceptor in angular 5. I am not able to get the error response and error status code in Chrome and but able to get in IE below is my HttpInterceptor code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpResponse } 
from '@angular/common/http';
import { finalize, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class LoggingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
const startTime = Date.now();
let status: string;

return next.handle(req).pipe(
    tap(
      event => {
        status = '';
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          status = 'succeeded';
        }
      },
      error => {
        if(error instanceof HttpErrorResponse)  {
          console.log(error.error.message) 
          // Above message is printing in IE but no in chorme.
       }
     }
    ),
    finalize(() => {

    })
);
 }

}
```

In the above Error block the message and status code I am able to see in IE but not in Chrome. Kindly help me how to resolve this.

**Edit:
I am consuming data from different origin  and cors is enabled in web services**

Comment: have you tried: `if(error instanceof HttpErrorResponse || error instanceof ErrorEvent)` ? Or just without the type checking and see if chrome reaches the error at all?

Comment: what's the actual HTTP error you're testing this with? Is there an HTTP error thrown in Chrome?

Comment: I am trying to handle 500 interal server error with some custom meesage thrown by service

Comment: Is this a CORs request or on the same origin?

Comment: It is a CORS request

Comment: the CORS headers of the request itself are most likely at fault.

Comment: Put `debugger;` statement in your error handling section and check what kind of error object do you receive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the issue, It is due to not setting response headers on errors at server side. Server is  throwing exception directly for errors without setting response headers. I have set response headers at server side and now I am able to see the error message in chrome.

Still I am confused how come IE able to respond on this errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `HttpErrorResponse` import, a more browser agnostic approach would be to look at the error status, rather than the error message.

```
  if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      console.log(err.status);
  }
```

I believe IE uses Friendly error messages where other browsers don't
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/08/18/friendly-http-error-pages/

Here's a fairly up to date Medium article on Interceptors and usage which may clarify some things
https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Hope this helps

Comment: with wrongful CORS headers, Chrome returns error code "0", while it should not ...therefore this is not exactly a solution to the problem.

Comment: Grant implemented  the same  before posting here but no luck

Comment: Martin you are right it is due to wrong ful headers